# Syntax Error while using ReactDOMServer with Sass

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-dom-server

Im getting Syntax Error like below while using `ReactDOMServer` and `Sass` in my project:

> SyntaxError: /Users/ceyhun23/Sites/{project_name}/lib/components/common/Menu/Menu.scss: Unexpected character '#' (1:3)
>   0|server   | > 1 | img#logo{
>   0|server   |     |    ^
>   0|server   |   2 |   height: 100%;
>   0|server   |   3 | }

`webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      Assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib/assets/'),
    }
  },
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './lib/components/App.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib/assets/images')
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

This is my server scripts with `ExpressJs`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

import App from './components/App';

const serverRender = () => {
  return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <App />
  );
};

export default serverRender;
```

`Menu` component is child component of `App` component, and `Menu.scss` imported like below:

```
import React from 'react';

import './Menu.scss';

export default class Menu extends React.Component {
  render() {...}
}
```

and Finally `Menu.scss` :

```
img#logo{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Do you have any suggestion? Could you tell me please, whats wrong with my source ?

Thanks!

Comment: javascript does not support "IMPORTING" scss files.

Comment: @ReiDien, do you have any suggestion ? with these sources and using webpack I can achive running client-side React Application with no error

Comment: use bundlers, webpack, rollup etc.

Comment: @ReiDien Im using webpack, I did edit my question post and added its configuration

Comment: if you are using babel, add babel config on webpack

Comment: @ReiDien i have babel config in package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long investigation I found **2** type of **solution** for this issue thanks to [**dimaip**](https://github.com/dimaip/)! 
So , Im giving related links below you can check if you have this problem like me:

1) 1st is adding env variable to check in webpack for importing css or not, and using .css file seperated from `bundle.js`
For this solution you can check this [link](https://github.com/dimaip/server-side-rendering/commit/53d2ffa7bc9319722addced5bb94c5b231726a1b)

2) 2nd solution is using webpack for server-side `renderToString` function and using it inside `app.get('*')` 
Additionaly, you can check this [link](https://github.com/dimaip/server-side-rendering/commit/53d2ffa7bc9319722addced5bb94c5b231726a1b)

Thanks!!!